# Forge viewer Isolate and Reset

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

In Forge viewer, I isolated the elements using dbid's. But I don't know how to revert back to normal, in other words how to reset after isolation.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite straightforward. Just call `viewer.isolate()`